# When use $@ to pass all arguments in bash, why '-n' cannot be passed

Tags: bash

When I try to use the $@ to pass arguments in bash, it seems if -n come first in the arguments, the return symbol '\n' is removed.

```
[...]$ test(){ echo "$@";}
[...]$ test 1 2 3
```

return

```
[...]$ 1 2 3
[...]$
```

but

```
[...]$ test -n 1 2 3
```

return

```
[...]$1 2 3[...]$
```

-n disappear and seems return symbol \n is removed due to '-n'

Is '-n' an special option for $@? How can I pass -n with $@

Comment: `test` is not a good name for a function; the shell already provides a function named `test`. Use a different name (one that tells what the function does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `test -n 1 2 3`, `echo "$@"` will become `echo -n 1 2 3 4` where `-n` become `echo`'s option which prevents `echo` from printing a NEWLINE char.

You can write like this:

```
Test() { printf '%s\n' "$*"; }
```

(Note that `Test() { printf -- "$*"; }` mentioned in another deleted answer may not work. Try `Test %d a b c` and you'll find out why.)

Comment: Thank you, now I understand the issue.

Answer (score 3):

`-n`is special option for `echo` (remove final `\n`)

You need use `$*` instead of `$@`

```
test(){ echo "$*";}
```

- `$@` expanded as `"$1" "$2" "$3" ... "$n"`
- `$*` expanded as `"$1x$2x$3x...$n"`, where `x` is the value of IFS variable i.e.

`"$*"` is one long string and `$IFS` act as an separator or token delimiters.

`echo "$@"`  ==> `echo "-n" "1" "2" "3"` ==> `1 2 3` (without "\n")

`echo "$*"`  ==> `echo "-n 1 2 3"` ==> `-n 1 2 3` (with "\n")

Comment: This is not the reason why `-n` is not showing up. And this will still fail to  print `test -n` or `test -neE`.

Comment: I agree with you is not single reason, but change `$@` by `$*` solve the problem for me.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand the issue